# What's the best way to diagnose 'not responding' programs?

Tags: windows-7, freeze, thinkpad

Normally I consider myself very proficient when it comes to electronics/computers, however I am having a bit of a hard time tracking down an annoying thing that randomly makes Outlook or other programs go into 'not responding' mode. I will try to explain the situation and what I did so far as good as possible.

- it does not help to 'wait a bit' as is sometimes the case, even after 15 mins or more and no load on the system the program will not recover, the only solution is to kill or restart the program
- `procmon` etc. did not help so far as no process seems to be behaving abnormally.
- disabled truecrypt (still happening), disabled anti-virus ...

System: Lenovo T400 with Win 7 32 bit, 2,53 Ghz, 4 GB Ram, 500 GB Hdd (replacing the original 320 Gb), Intel and Ati switchable graphics (set to discrete in bios atm).

Should I check the disk for errors? Should I run `memtest` first or replace some memory sticks? I just think that if it were the disk or RAM, problems should be more widespread or if they occur freeze more than one program. Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Initially you might check the Event Viewer (Right-click "Computer" on the Start menu and select "Manage") for signs of errors being caused at the application level.

Comment: I'd first track down when it does this. Is this when Outlook loads? Is it when it sync main? etc etc